# Does this imply that the domain is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: B \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function, does this imply that $B$ is also bounded? I was reading a proof about if $B$ is also closed, then $B$ is compact (by HB). So I am assuming this is true, but I am not sure why.

Why is $A$ compact then? I know $A$ is closed, but we don't know if it is bounded or not.

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $f:B\to\mathbb R$ setting is unrelated to the question you ask about the proof in the book:

> Why is A compact then?

Because A is a closed rectangle hence A is bounded and closed.

Later on, à propos another example, you state:

> We know that $B_ϵ$ is closed, but nothing about being bounded.

Of course we know that $B_ϵ$ is bounded since $B_ϵ\subseteq A$ and $A$ is a rectangle.

Comment: Maybe this was a bad example, but this may seem like a dumb question. What if $A$ was an infinitely large rectangle? Then it can't be bounded right?

Comment: There is no such thing as an infinitely large rectangle.

Comment: Can't we consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ as an infinitely large rectangle/cube?

Comment: No we can't. $ $

Comment: But we consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ as an infinitely large ball no?

Comment: Some people do, sometimes, yes.

Comment: So why can't we consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be an infinitely large cube?

Comment: Because we don't. As shown by the two pages reproduced in your question.

Comment: so then is it convention? He *could* have considered $\mathbb{R}^n$ as an infinitely large cube. In fact, he could have replaced "closed rectangle" with "closed balls" no?

Comment: it appears the author defines $A = \prod [a_i,b_i]$ so it is compact from the get-go. I am not sure why he calls it "closed" instead of compact.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously not. For example, you could take $f$ to be a constant function, then $B$ can be anything...

The thing about $B$ being closed implying that it's compact is purely topological has nothing to do with the existence of a bounded function on $B$. Though, it is true that any continuous function on a compact set is bounded.

Comment: Then what is the theorem in my book saying?

Comment: @oxeimon I believe you forgot continuous in your last sentence.

Comment: @sidht I believe here is the intuition of the lemma: you can approximate the difference of upper and lower sum of a function $f$ on a set $A$ by the amount of oscillation $f$ has. Since oscillation is a "local" property and upper/lower sum are "global", thus the actual bound of course also depends on the size of the set $A$. Now if $A$ is unbounded instead of a box, the inequality holds trivially.

Comment: @Xiao, I was actually referring to the comment about compactness.